# generate table 3 x 4 with array php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I make a query to the database and want to get the data in a table with 3 columns by 4 lines. What gives 12 elements. But let's imagine that in the database, has 13 elements, I will create another table.

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
          echo $row['name_file']; //print what is inside the array
     }
}
```

I know I'll have to do two cycles for, but I'm having trouble. Will is the best way to print the data?
thanks

Comment: Not going to give you the whole code, but in the loop you should use conditions like:`if( $i == 0 || ($i-1) % 12 == 0) echo "<table>";` and `if( $i == 0 || ($i-1) % 3 == 0) echo "<tr>";` (**You don't need 2 cycles for it**)

Comment: See my answer below, I fixed error there. Now its should be ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
$i = 0;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($i % 12 == 0) {
      // Table ID dont need to be rounded, because $i % 12 == 0, so $i / 12 is integer, not float...
      echo '<table id="Table'.($i / 12 + 1).'">'."\n";
    }

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
      echo '<tr>'."\n";
    }

    echo '<td>'.$row['name_file'].'</td>'."\n";

    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
      echo '</tr>'."\n";
    }

    if ($i % 12 == 11) {
      echo '</table>'."\n";
    }

    $i++;
  }

  if ($i % 3 > 0) {
    echo '</tr>'."\n";
  }

  if ($i % 12 > 0) {
    echo '</table>'."\n";
  }
}
```

F.e. lets say, we have name_file = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19; then it will output this:

```
<table id="Table1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="Table2">
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is the way, but is printing one per line. thanks for help

Comment: Also I added there 2 conditions, at the end, to close opened tr and table tags. Now its 100% ok.

Comment: for each table you create, if I want to renumber the table created, for exemple, Table1, Table2, etc.. where do I start this numbering?

Comment: If you mean ID for each table, I change code for that, to have IDs like Table1, Table2,...

Comment: sorry, but I've been testing and if we have more than 24 elemenentos, ie, will generate more than two tables, the other elements are added to the second table instead of creating the third. do you see the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39924/discussion-between-legionar-and-pc-oc)

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = 4; $cells = 3;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery limit ".($rows * $cells));
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $i++;
        echo $row['name_file'];
        if ($i % $cells == 0) {
            echo "<br/>";
        } else {
            echo " ";
        }
    }
}
```

is it that do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

This will print three results in arow
and continue to do as required .

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $vertical_rows = 1;
 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
      if($vertical_rows == 1)echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row['name_file']."</td>";

      if($vertical_rows == 3){
         echo "</tr>";
         $vertical_rows = 1;
        }
 }
 echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to deal with a database is using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Assuming you get the data into an array counting 15 items

```
$data = array_chunk($items, 12, true); 
// $data contains array(12 items), array(3 items), preserving array keys

foreach($data as $table)
{
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($table as $row)
    {
        printf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>', $row['field_name1'], $row['field_name2']);    
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code just prints the rows without cells. Not sure if i understood you correctly, but if you want to print a table, try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['name_file'];
    $i++;
    if($i >= 4) {
        echo "<br>";
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

Too stupid too read - not tested, but should work.^^

```
echo "<table><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>".$row['name_file']."</td>";
    $i++;
    if($i >= 4) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $i = 0;
    }
}
echo "</table>"
```

Comment: He asked for a table.